# Are SP server web config files changed after an SharePoint update/patching

Tags: sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

Its maybe a stupid question for someone, but I was wondering if a SharePoint update does change a web config file content. I want to do some changes over some of our SP servers web config files and I was not sure if those changes are going to be lost/reset after I do a SharePoint patching.
Exactly does the SharePoint wizard do those changes or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be in addition to making certain changes/retracting/deploying Web Applications. You shouldn't be updating web.config files by hand but instead using the [`WebConfigModification` class](https://docs.microsoft.com/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb861909(v%3doffice.14)) to make the alterations. There are implementations of this via [PowerShell script](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-script-changes-to-the-sharepoint-web-config-file/).

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks for the script, I am aware of the WebConfigModification class, my question was more if the SP patching is doing a change over the web config files, not how I should do a change.